# How do I view the occurence of my search on Google?

Tags: google-chrome, search, search-engines, google-search

Often times when you type something into google, your phrase will come up in the little search preview but when you click the link itself lo and behold you cannot find your phrase anywhere. I remember (on Google Chrome, atleast) google used to have a little button which you can press which previews the whole page and highlights where your phrase is located on that page but I don't get it anymore although to be truthful that could just be an addon.

So does anyone know a way for google to allow me to view the occurrence of my phrase on the preview or is this functionality provided by an addon? I ask because many times google likes to feed me pages where my phrase is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [*Cache*](http://www.google.com/intl/en/help/features_list.html#cached). If the page doesn’t forbid it, you can access the cached version by clicking at the little green triangle next to the URL:

> [image: Google search result: link to cached version (JS)]

Note that this link requires activated JavaScript and enabled cookies. If you have disabled JavaScript, you’ll probably still see the direct link:

> [image: Google search result: link to cached version (no JS)]

You can open a cached page directly by using the `cache:` prefix (followed by the URL) in the search. [Example](https://www.google.com/search?q=cache:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange_Network):

```
cache:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange_Network
```

Answer (score 1):

That used to be available when you loaded the cached version of the search result. However Google has removed that feature and expect you to use the find feature in the browser. Ctrl + f opens the find box.

Comment: why did they remove it? was pretty nifty :( sometimes the text is hidden in a comment thread

Answer (score 0):

It might not be there at all -- ISTR that Google sometimes indexes pages by words that appear in other pages that link to them.  Also, even if a word is in the HTML file, it might not be displayed by your browser -- do “View Source”, and then search through that.